# Postgres: creating role and password from CLI, nested quotes problems

Tags: bash, postgresql, sudo, quotes

I'm trying to create a postgres role and password from bash. However, it seems I'm struggling with the escaping of quotes.

Running:

```
$ sudo su - postgres -c '''psql -c "CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'somepass';" '''
```

Produces:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "somepass"
LINE 1: CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD somepass;
```

Other unsuccessful variations I've tried;

```
sudo su - postgres -c """psql -c "CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'somepass';" """
sudo su - postgres -c $''' psql -c "CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD \'pass\';" '''
```

How can I deal with the nested quotes, and get postgres to create the role from cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'''` and `$'''` are pointless. They're equivalent to `'`.

That's because `'''foo'` is parsed as an empty quoted string `''` immediately followed by another quoted string `'foo'`, which is just `foo`.

To get a single `'` into a single-quoted shell string, use `'\''`:

```
sudo su - postgres -c 'psql -c "CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD '\''somepass'\'';"'
```

The reason this works: `'foo'\''bar'` is parsed as a quoted part (`'foo'`) followed by an unquoted but backslash-escaped character (`\'`) followed by another quoted part (`'bar'`). These are all concatenated to form `foo'bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all quoting problems by using a here-document :

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su - postgres -c psql <<OMG
CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'somepass';
-- DROP USER testuser ;
OMG
```

---

BTW: you *dont* need a script for this, it will work just as well in an interactive shell. (I just used the script to test it)